# jquery animation chain structure

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a jquery animation chain, but some how it's not set up quite right, I'm not sure if I just over looked something, or if I'm doing this wrong, but I have a feeling it's something small. Thanks for any help on this!

JS

```
function paper_zoom_in() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#paper-citizen").animate({
            opacity:1
        },{
            duration:300,
            queue:false
        });
        $("#paper-blur").animate({
            width:350,
            opacity:0,
            marginRight:30
        },{
            duration:320,
            queue:false
        });
        $("#paper_1").animate({
            left:150,
            top:90,
            opacity:"1"
        },{
            duration:350,
            queue:false,
            complete:function() {
                $("#paper_1").animate({
                    left:230,
                    top:120,
                    opacity:".6"
                },{
                    duration:450,
                    queue:false,
                    complete:function() {
                        $("#paper_1").animate({
                            left:140,
                            top:140,
                            opacity:".3"
                        },{
                            duration:500,
                            queue:false,
                            complete:function() {
                                $("#paper_1").animate({
                                    left:210,
                                    top:160,
                                    opacity:0
                                },{
                                    duration:500,
                                    queue:false
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    },450);
}
```

Comment: Paste your `html` for better understanding.

Comment: Looks like you need to close your parenthesis for 2 animate functions: http://jsfiddle.net/Jag96/JN8hW/